# How to update exsiting row in database in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new in laravel and I want to update an existing row in database,but  when I click on send button in view (for example *127.0.0.1/laravel/public/Article/update/3* ) I encounter the following error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:

Here is my code

```
Route


Route::get('Article/edit/{id}','ArticleController@edit');

Route::get('Article/update/{id}','ArticleController@update');
```

---

```
ArticleController


public function edit($id)
{

$change = Article::find($id);

    return view('edit',compact('change'));


}


public function Update($id, Request $request)
{



    Article::update($request->all());

    return redirect('Article');

}
```

---

```
Model


public $table = 'Article';

protected $fillable = ['title' , 'body'];
```

---

```
edit.blade.php


<h1>ویرایش بست {{$change->title}}</h1>


{!! Form::model($change ,['method'=>'patch' , 'url'=>['Article/update' , $change->id ]]) !!}

{!! Form::label('title','عنوان') !!}
{!! Form::text('title') !!}
<br>

{!! Form::label('body','متن') !!}
{!! Form::textarea('body') !!}

<br>
{!! Form::submit('send') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}



@if($errors->any())
<ul class ='alert alert-danger'>
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)


<li>{{ $error }}</li>

@endforeach


</ul>

@endif
```

Comment: You are using a `get` route and you are expecting it to catch a `PATCH` or `POST` request. See the error?

Comment: "it dose not work" does not help me or anyone else to figure out what the hell doesn't work. Seriously, if you're not going to help us help you then why waste your or our time?

Comment: sorry i cant speak english very well , but i test your solution and i encounter that same error , and i test another way for debug this error but i dont know what the hell doesn't work!!!!

Comment: `Route::get('Article/update/{id}','ArticleController@update');` is wrong. It must be `Route::patch('Article/update/{id}', 'ArticleController@update');`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to resolve routing issues with Laravel is to use 'artisan'.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan

If you use this command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

You'll see every possible route and HTTP verb available for use.  Your error is in the RouteCollection so you can always fix these issues by looking at your `app/http/routes.php` file.

You defined a route as follows:

```
Route::get('Article/update/{id}','ArticleController@update');
```

Then you call that route via your form as follows:

```
{!! Form::model($change ,['method'=>'patch' , 'url'=>['Article/update' , $change->id ]]) !!}
```

Your `routes.php` GET definition does not match your form's PATCH method, so you're getting a method not allowed exception because the PATCH route is not defined.

You need this line of code in your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::patch('article/update/{id}','ArticleController@update');
```

I would highly recommend using this instead of defining each method individually:

```
Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');
```

Then run the following command again with artisan to see all routes created:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Good answer, better than mine. +1 @Kyle